# Show that the product topology is indeed a topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_1,\tau_1)$ and $(X_2, \tau_2)$ be topological spaces. Let $\tau$ be the product topology on $X_1 \times X_2$, that is, $\tau = \{ \cup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B_i)  : A_i \in \tau_1, B_i \in \tau_2,  \text{ for any index set }  I \}$ .
Show that $\tau$ is indeed a topology.

**Attempt:**

The first two conditions are simple:

1: Clearly $X_1\times X_2, \emptyset \in \tau$

2: Clearly any union of sets in $\tau $ also belongs to $\tau$.

I am struggling to show that if $C_i \in \tau$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ then $\cap_{I=1}^{n}C_i \in \tau$. I would appreciate some help!

Comment: You can try to show the intersection of any two basis or subbasis elements satisfy the condition with the help of the two given topology.

Answer (score 1):

Show A×B $\cap$ U×V = (A $\cap$ U)×(B $\cap$ V).

Conclude the intersection of two base sets of the product topology is in the topology.  Proceed to larger intersections by induction.